# WP_Query Taxonomy categories filtering

Tags: wp-query, categories, woocommerce-offtopic

Have a widget that's currently filtering a set of categories, and need to make it support more than one set of categories.

Right now the code is something like this:

```
$query_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $categories,
                    'operator' => 'AND',
                ),
            ),
        );
```

So, basically, it's filtering products that have x, y and z categories.
Now I need it to filter products that have x and y, OR x and z.
I've sketched this:

```
        $query_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND'
            ),
        );

        if(is_array($tags)){
            $query_args['tax_query']['relation'] = 'OR';
            foreach($tags as $tagGroup){
                array_push($query_args['tax_query'], array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => implode(',', $tagGroup),
                    'operator' => 'AND'
                ));
            }
        }else{
            array_push($query_args['tax_query'], array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $categories,
                'operator' => 'AND',
            ));
        }
```

But it's still not filtering products as I need.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can nest your tax queries. Just make sure you use `OR` as the first relation and `AND` relation on the nested tax queries.

```
$filter_group_a = array(
  'relation' => 'AND',
  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => $term_a,
  ),
  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => $term_b,
  ),
);

$filter_group_b = array(
  'relation' => 'AND',
  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => $term_a,
  ),
  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => $term_c,
  ),
)

$query_args = array(
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    $filter_group_a,
    $filter_group_b,
  )
);
```

You could write some fancy loop that builds the `$filter_groups` and pushes them to the `$query_args['tax_query']` array.

Answer (score 0):

you can nest multiple tax queries like so:

```
$query_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'tax_query' => [
            'relation' => 'OR',
            [
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $x_y,
                    'operator' => 'AND',
                ],
            ],
            [
                'relation' => 'AND',
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $x_z,
                    'operator' => 'AND',
                ],
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'something_something',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $z,
                    'operator' => 'AND',
                ]
            ],

        ],
    );
```

i took your example code, so not sure about all the values you have there, but basically you can combine AND and OR..
more info [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters)

Comment: There is no such `'operator'` parameter value like `'AND'`.

Comment: the operator `IN` means "has one of the values from the `terms` table", the operator `AND` means "has **all** the values from the `terms` table"

Comment: @MaxYudin if would read, you would know better: first off, i say, that i'm not sure about the parameters that the questioner is using, i'm just copying his stuff. second i link to the docs, and yeah, the operator does exist.. <3